# How do I turn a JavaScript object into Map[String,String]?

Tags: scala.js

In `index-dev.html` I load a local JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="map.js"></script>
```

`map.js` structurally (not literally) looks like this:

```
var a2b = {
  "a": "My life closed twice before its close—",
  "b": "It yet remains to see",
  "c": "If Immortality unveil",
  "d": "A third event to me",

  "e": "So huge, so hopeless to conceive",
  "f": "As these that twice befell.",
  "g": "Parting is all we know of heaven,",
  "h": "And all we need of hell.",

  "z": "Emily Dickinson, 1830-1886"
}
```

I figured out how to load this object into Scala.js:

```
val a2b = js.Dynamic.global.a2b
```

Now `a2b` is of type `Dynamic`.  What I want is `Map[String,String]`.

I tried this:

```
val a2b = js.Dynamic.global.a2b.asInstanceOf[Map[String,String]]
```

but that didn't work.  What should I do to get a `Map[String,String]`?

Comment: This looks similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31655070/how-to-convert-map-to-json-object-in-scala-js

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key thing is that it *isn't* a `Map`, which is why it's not working. But it *is* a `js.Dictionary`. So use that for your `asInstanceOf` instead, and if you actually need a Scala `Map`, use the `toMap` function on that:

```
val a2b = js.Dynamic.global.a2b.asInstanceOf[js.Dictionary[String]].toMap
```